# Compare row by row based on two conditional statements in R

Tags: r

I have a matrix with two columns of the following form:

```
AAA 1/1/0            
AAA 1/0/1    
BBB 1/1/0      
BBB 1/1/0      
BBB 1/1/0    
BBB 1/1/0     
CCC 1/1/0   
CCC 1/0/1    
CCC 1/1/0     
CCC 1/0/1
```

I would like to obtain the following matrix filtered by identical values in the first column and none identical in the second:

```
AAA 1/1/0  
AAA 1/0/1   
CCC 1/1/0  
CCC 1/0/1
```

Any help would be appreciated !!!

Tara

Comment: I couldn't find an answer, but here's the code to reproduce the data: `data <- data.frame(x1 = c(rep('AAA', 2), rep('BBB', 4), rep('CCC', 4)), x2 = c('1/1/0', '1/0/1', rep('1/1/0', 5), '1/0/1', '1/1/0', '1/0/1'))`. Maybe doing something with `unique(data)` will give you what you want, but it still shows the `'BBB'` line.

Answer (score 1):

Using data and suggestion from @wleoncio:

```
data <- data.frame(x1 = c(rep('AAA', 2), rep('BBB', 4), rep('CCC', 4)), x2 = c('1/1/0', '1/0/1', rep('1/1/0', 5), '1/0/1', '1/1/0', '1/0/1'))

library(data.table)
dt = data.table(data)

# setkey, to make sure we only do the unique on the first two columns
setkey(dt, x1, x2)

# unique almost gets us there, we just need to also filter out the loners
unique(dt)[, .SD[.N > 1], by = x1]
#    x1    x2
#1: AAA 1/1/0
#2: AAA 1/0/1
#3: CCC 1/1/0
#4: CCC 1/0/1
```

Answer (score 1):

To me it looks like you want to keep:

- Those rows with identical values in the first column, ***but also***
- non-identical rows in the second column

This rules out the rows with `BBB` because the values in the second column are all identical. If that is the case then you can use `duplicated`, but you will also need to do a little further subsetting to remove those rows (thanks to **@wleoncio** for the data):

```
data <- data.frame(x1 = c(rep('AAA', 2), rep('BBB', 4), rep('CCC', 4)), x2 = c('1/1/0', '1/0/1', rep('1/1/0', 5), '1/0/1', '1/1/0', '1/0/1'))

newdat <- data[ ! duplicated(data) , ]
   x1    x2
1 AAA 1/1/0
2 AAA 1/0/1
3 BBB 1/1/0
7 CCC 1/1/0
8 CCC 1/0/1

keep <- unclass( table(newdat$x1) ) != 1
  AAA   BBB   CCC 
 TRUE FALSE  TRUE 

newdat[ newdat$x1 %in% unique(newdat$x1 )[keep]  , ]
   x1    x2
1 AAA 1/1/0
2 AAA 1/0/1
7 CCC 1/1/0
8 CCC 1/0/1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. that works well for dataframes with two columns, but what about df with more columns. Is there a loop solution ?

Comment: @Tara you will need to respecify the problem a bit. Do you want separate results for each of the columns? e.g. x1+x2, then x1+x3, then x1+x4... x1+xn?